# Please vote on tag synonyms for [tag:indentation]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[indentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation) has 3 [synonym proposals](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/indentation/synonyms). If you have a tag-score of 5 or greater, you can vote on the synonyms at that link.

The current proposals for synonyms are

- [indent](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indent)
- [smartindent](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartindent)
- [autoindent](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoindent)

Comment: Also If you have a strong point for or against any of these synonyms, please feel free to add it in an answer below.